# Shiny server is the same as NGNX?

Tags: r, nginx, shiny, shiny-server

We were doing some research on the configuration of Shiny server then we noticed that the config syntax is virtually the same as Nginx? Does anyone have a confirmation on this? If that is true we plan a different stack system architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Shiny Server and Shiny Server Pro are not based on nginx they are using **Node.js** to provide their web server functionality. Please see the according [answer](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218294977-What-web-server-is-used-by-Shiny-Server-and-Shiny-Server-Pro-) in the RStudio FAQ.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It's not "Link-only". The essential part of the answer is: They are using Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

just had a bit of a poke in their [github repository](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server) and it looks to be pretty custom code and they're just reusing the syntax/variable naming of Nginx.

config parsing seems to be done in [lib/router/config-router.js](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/blob/master/lib/router/config-router.js) where you can find references to things like `'log_dir'`

I'd therefore probably put some sort of proxy between it and the internet (if that's your plan)